# get text files name(number) from a directory, and use the file name(number) to look for data in a separate text file

Tags: python, list, directory, text-files

I am new to python. I have a few text files in a directory, and a seperate textfile maintained the original links for each of the text files. Ie, I have 1.txt,2.txt and 3.txt saved in the directory, and I have weblink text file(line 1(wiki.com/a) is the link for 1.txt, line 2(wiki.com/b is the link for 2.txt...). I am able to get the text file names, but I can't use the result to find the links from the weblink text file.

```
#first part
path = 'C:\\Users\\PycharmProjects\\pythonProject1\\Document'
files = [os.path.splitext(filename)[0] for filename in os.listdir(path)]
print(files) #result from here is ['1', '2', '3']

#second part
file = open("C:\\Users\\PycharmProjects\\pythonProject1\\link.txt")
specified_lines = files #files are taking the result from first part

for pos, l_num in enumerate(file):
    if pos in specified_lines:
        print(l_num)
```

if i use specified_lines = [0,1,2] then the function works, how do i incorporate the output from my first part into my second part? As of right now, specified_lines = files in the second part return nothing.

Comment: You mention these are separate functions - are you passing `files` to the second function? If you do a `print(files)` in the second function what does it say?

Comment: yes, i am passing the files from the first function to the second function to find the respective link for each file number in the link.txt. when i print(files) under the print(l_num) in the second function, it returns nothing.

Comment: could you include the lines where you call those functions?

Comment: not sure if i did it correctly, but my whole codes just combine the first and second part of what i shared in my post description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this helps.

1. Try printing `pos`, I see its 0 based so you may want to offset `pos`
2. Try converting the `pos` from integer to string before searching

```py
import os

path = '.'
files = [os.path.splitext(filename)[0] for filename in os.listdir(path)]
print(files) #result from here is ['1', '2', '3']

#second part
file = open("weblink")
specified_lines = files #files are taking the result from first part

for pos, l_num in enumerate(file):
    print(pos)
    if str(pos+1) in specified_lines:
        print(l_num)
```

Output from my try:

```
['orig', 'weblink', 'notes', '3', '2', '1']
0
wiki.com/a

1
wiki.com/b

2
wiki.com/c
```